# What is the problem of c++ no value sort()?

Tags: c++

While I was studying algorithms, I was trying to run a sort order, but there was an error.
It says there are no members in the value, but there is an error even if you declare the structure. Do you know why?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct table{
int startValue;
int finishValue;
};

bool cmp(table f, table s)
{
    if (f.finishValue == s.finishValue)
        return f.startValue < s.startValue;
    else
        return f.finishValue < s.finishValue;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int maxTimeTable;
    cin >> maxTimeTable;

    vector<table>t(maxTimeTable);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxTimeTable; i++)
    {
        cin >> t[i].startValue >> t[i].finishValue;
    }

    sort(t.startValue(), t.finishValue(), cmp); //Error Occurrence Point

    int cnt = 0;
    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++)
    {
        if (n <= t[i].startValue)
        {
            n = t[i].finishValue;
            cnt++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `t` is a `vector<table>`, not a `table`. Not sure why you expected the `table` members to be present in a `vector<table>`, or why you wrote `()` after them. You're looking for `sor(f.begin(), f.end(), cmp);`.

Comment: have you tried using a map or vector instead of a custom structure?

Comment: `t.startValue()` doesn't make sense to me. `t` is complete **vector**. It should be `t[0].startValue()`. Think about it.

Comment: Thank you all so much.
I think I lacked the grammar of c++.
I thought the sort would arrange the vector directly, but I was mistaken.
Thank you so much for your response.
I've been thinking about it for seven hours today, and I wouldn't have been able to debug it if it weren't for you guys tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

You are treating `t` as a `table`-object

```
sort(t.startValue(), t.finishValue(), cmp); //Error Occurrence Point
```

but it's not, right? `t` is defined as `vector<table>t(maxTimeTable);`. And correctly, the compiler provides an error, since `vector<table>` does not have a method `startValue` nor a `finishValue`.

You probably meant to sort the vector by accessing the iterator to the first element, and to the last element:

```
sort(t.begin(), t.end(), cmp);
```

Comment: Correct. Good explanation! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with my problem. Thanks to you, I can sleep tonight. Thank you very much. I think grammar is really weak because it is moving from c to c++. Thank you so much for your help.